# Node.js - async.queue() - How to end a task to allow more to run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, queue

I am using async's queue method to queue up tasks. I set concurrency to 20. I have a little over 2100 tasks to complete, however when queue reaches 20, it quits processing more tasks. Here is what I have:

```
syncrequest = require('sync-request');

o.getObj = function(site, link){
    global.task.comment(site, 'Pulling page ' + link, function(){});
    try{
        q.push({url: link}, function(){
            console.log("processed" + link);
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

var q = async.queue(function(task, callback){
        var body = syncrequest('GET', base+'/'+task.url).getBody();
        $$$ = cheerio.load(body);
        var obj = {
            title: $$$('#title').text(),
            link: task.url,
        };
        $$$ = null;
        objs.push(obj);
        return;
},20);
```

The callback `console.log("processed" + link);` never gets called, so I'm assuming that it thinks the task is still running. I'm logging the number of total objects and the number of objects pushed on a `setInterval` and it logs:

```
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 3
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 6
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 9
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 12
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 15
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 18
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 20
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 20
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 20
app-0 (out): 2210 ... 20
...
```

Should I be doing something to formally finish a task to clear room for another?

Comment: Well, your tasks never call `callback`?!

Comment: @Bergi Ah, damn. So you're right!

Comment: Actually your tasks don't look very asynchronous. Why are you using `async` at all instead of a `for` loop?

Comment: @Bergi When I used a for loop I was getting this error: `error: spawn emfile`

Comment: Odd, that seems to have something to do with child processes. Are sync-request or cheerio spawning processes? If they do, its odd that they still behave synchronous; don't they have an async api as well?

Comment: @Bergi I thought the same thing too, but I couldn't find an answer. I plan on looking into it further, but for now this was the only thing getting me past that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call your callback()

```
var q = async.queue(function(task, callback){
        var body = syncrequest('GET', base+'/'+task.url).getBody();
        $$$ = cheerio.load(body);
        var obj = {
            title: $$$('#title').text(),
            link: task.url,
        };
        $$$ = null;
        objs.push(obj);
        return callback();
},20);
```